# roblox LUA Expected 'end' (to close 'than' at line 3), got '='

Tags: lua, roblox

```
function teleportTo(placeCFrame)
    local plyr = game.Players.LocalPlayer;
    if plyr.Character then
        return plyr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = placeCFrame; 
    end
end

teleportTo(game:GetService("Workspace").game:GetService("Workspace").Zeppelin.FuelTank1.Tank.CFrame)
```

my code is here, idk much about coding thanks for helping
and if you told me how to make the player teleport to a moving object it would be so super

Comment: function teleportTo(placeCFrame)
    local plyr = game.Players.LocalPlayer;
    if plyr.Character then
        return plyr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = placeCFrame; 
    end
 end

teleportTo(game:GetService("Workspace").game:GetService("Workspace").Zeppelin.FuelTank1.Tank.CFrame)

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you what is going on.

When the code was being interpreted line by line, it expected the next symbol to be `end`, but instead it got `=`.

That means that something about how you're using the equals sign is incorrect. So when we look at the line :

```
return plyr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = placeCFrame
```

You cannot assign a value on the same line as a `return` command. `return` is used to pipe a value out of a function so it can be used where the function was called.

But I'm pretty sure that isn't what you intended, you just want to set a player's position. So to fix your issue, remove the `return`.

```
if plyr.Character then
    plyr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = placeCFrame
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because `=` is usually defined as setting a value, and no code can be executed after a return or it will error

If you wanted to, you could add return after all the code is done executing